# Como dar formato de fecha un campo obtenido de la base de datos?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

Obtengo un campo de la base de datos de tipo string

campo = `20180117`

Estoy tratando de hacer algo similar a esto

`datetime.strptime(campo, '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%Y-%m-%d-T%H:%M:%S')`

`2018-01-17-T00:00:00`

Alguna idea o sugerencia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Claro, mira, con tu mismo ejemplo:

```
import datetime

dt=datetime.datetime.strptime("20180117",'%Y%m%d')

print(dt)
```

Arroja:

> 2018-01-17 00:00:00

[DEMO](https://repl.it/@meerkat999/CriminalIckyBumblebee)

Comment: Gracias los estaba haciendo mal